# How to run private dart pub server

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, dart-pub

I want a private pub server where only my team can publish and retrieve packages, unfortunately I haven't found *any* documentation regarding the deployment of the pub server.

I downloaded the [pub server](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang) and deployed it successfully to appengine.

I am now wondering what values should go in the `/admin` private keys section, and what they are for. Are they used to authenticate the users trying to access the packages?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question. There were a few discussions how to configure it in the Dart Google groups and maybe in dartbug.com. I wanted to poit out that there is a new approach, a rewrite in Dart https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang-dart

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There seems to be even less documentation for the dart version though. Is there any ETA for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aspects to consider here:

### REST api:

The first aspect is having a private pub package repository to which (maybe a limited amount of) developers can publish & access packages. The functionality required here is a narrow REST-like API. A write-up of what this API looks like can be found [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub_server/blob/master/lib/shelf_pubserver.dart#L26).

### UI Layer & Other things

The second aspect is having, on top of a private pub package repository, a web UI on which developers can search for packages, discover them, see uploaded versions, etc.

### Implementation of pub.dartlang.org

The pub.dartlang.org site tries to solve both of these aspects at the same time. It was not intended to be re-used for other users (even though it potentially could). The [python version](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang) of the site is in maintenance mode. The [dart version](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang-dart) is currently written to replace the python version. It will start with the exact same functionality & behavior as the python version.

Since the REST api is close to set-in-stone ATM, it makes sense that it is implemented only once and can be shared between pub servers. We therefore try to put this shared code into a common [package:pub_server](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub_server) package.

If you intend to re-use the pub.dartlang.org code, here is the explanation on what happens: The application is an AppEngine application and stores tarballs in Google Cloud Storage. The search functionality of the site is based on Google's Custom Search API. Metadata is stored in datastore. The private key for read/write access to a GCS bucket and for the Custom Search API is stored in the datastore and will be lazily loaded. The dart version can currently also be run outside of AppEngine by using ServiceAccount credentials and the REST api of datastore (you can see the plumbing layer in [bin/server_io.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang-dart/blob/master/app/bin/server_io.dart). Some limited set of configuration data is in the source code (e.g. service account email, GCS bucket name).